# Using For-loop to Free Textures from Memory

Tags: c++, concatenation

I have 23 textures loaded and I named them `t1, t2, ... , t23,`

I have a function that frees all textures, but I was hoping to make it more efficient (or use less code) to free them all.

Currently, it does this:

```
    FreeTexture(t1);
    FreeTexture(t2);
          .
          .
          .
    FreeTexture(t23);
```

So I tried to do something like this:

```
    for (int i=1; i< 23; i++){
        //i int-to-string
        //concatenate 't' + 'i_string'
        FreeTexture(ti);
    }
```

But I'm unsure of the best way to implement something like this.

Or maybe it's easier to put all the textures in an array and just iterate the array? `t[i]`?

**Update**

I've changed my code to this:

```
    int numberOfTextures = 23;
    std::vector<GLuint> v(numberOfTextures);

    v[1] = LoadTexture("resources/RoadTex1.raw", 512, 512);
    v[2] = LoadTexture("resources/RoadTex2.raw", 512, 512);
            .
            .
            .

    void freeTiles(){
        for (int i=1; i<=numberOfTextures; i++){
            FreeTexture(v[i]);
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Like this? No. Put your textures into a `std::vector`, and loop over that.

Comment: Ah. Thanks. I've updated my code. I think it's a correct implementation. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: I would highly recommend using [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) here as this code is NOT exception safe, the textures will not be freed if an exception is thrown before a call to your freeing loop. Whereas with RAII they would be freed when the `std::vector` was destructed.

Comment: Oh, nice call! I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
Texture *t[NUM_TEXTURES];

for(int i=0;i<NUM_TEXTURES;i++) {
    FreeTexture(t[i]);
}
```

Create an array of texture pointers, iterate over the array. This is the straight C edition. In C++ you can use a vector and use an iterator from begin to end.

My apologies, I missed the C++ request:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<Texture *> t;

for(std::vector<Texture *>::iterator i = t.begin(); i!= t.end(); ++i) {
    FreeTexture(*i);
}
```

Comment: Since this question is tagged `C++`, and not `C`, please consider adding the `std::vector` example.

Answer (score 0):

storing in std::vector is a good idea,,, and your for loop is good enough. but better way as @user2278777 said is to use iterators. another competent way is to use foreach

```
// for_each example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::for_each
#include <vector>       // std::vector

void myfunction (int i) {  // function:
  std::cout << ' ' << i;
}

struct myclass {           // function object type:
  void operator() (int i) {std::cout << ' ' << i;}
} myobject;

int main () {
  std::vector<int> myvector;
  myvector.push_back(10);
  myvector.push_back(20);
  myvector.push_back(30);

  std::cout << "myvector contains:";
  for_each (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), myfunction);
  std::cout << '\n';

  // or:
  std::cout << "myvector contains:";
  for_each (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), myobject);
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Output
myvector contains: 10 20 30
myvector contains: 10 20 30